# iTextSharp - Preserve fillable fields in existing PDF

Tags: pdf, itext, field

I have created an app that reads a PDF file, adds something to a specified field, sets a password on the document, then exists.

The application reads from PDF files that have fill-able fields on it.

This works fine. The field gets updated and the PDF saves without a problem - until I add in this:

```
PdfEncryptor.Encrypt(reader, output, true, null, "busspass13579", PdfWriter.ALLOW_SCREENREADERS);
```

The PDF then becomes completely flat with no fill-able fields.

Any ideas?